# Rails 3.2 & LESS: A few in application.css.less @imported LESS files do not trigger recompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less

I really don't know how to debug this, maybe somebody has an idea.

I have many LESS files which I import in `application.css.less`. We use Bootstrap, and we want to use the variables that are defined in it within our own styles, so we can't require the LESS files in the manifest (as required files don't seem to make their variables public to other required files).

Everything works nicely, except a few of the LESS files - when edited - don't trigger a recompile of the CSS! It seems to be quite random which do and which don't, and it's only 6 of them which don't (compared to about 25 in sum). When I require one of them in the manifest, it successfully leads to a recompile - if I @import it, it doesn't.

Any idea on how to debug this? If I rename one of them (e.g. from `time_records.less` to `time_records2.less`), it successfully trigger recompile after changes... So it has do do something with the names of these 6 specific files:

- calendars.less
- contacts.less
- folders.less
- handout.css.less
- print.css.less
- time_records.css.less

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you come up with any solution? I am facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

The latest edition of less-rails implements Import Hooks that should solve your problem. I realize this is a late answer and it may have not existed at the time.

**Import Hooks**

Any @import to a .less file will automatically declare that file as a sprockets dependency to the file importing it. This means that you can edit imported framework files and see changes reflected in the parent during development. So this:

```
@import "frameworks/bootstrap/mixins";

#leftnav { .border-radius(5px); }
```

Will end up acting as if you had done this below:

```
/*
 *= depend_on "frameworks/bootstrap/mixins.less"
*/

@import "frameworks/bootstrap/mixins";

#leftnav { .border-radius(5px); }
```

**The depend_on Directive**

depend_on path declares a dependency on the given path without including it in the bundle. This is useful when you need to expire an asset's cache in response to a change in another file.